# EF Core queries throw exceptions since VS2017 15.3

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, entity-framework-core

I updated to VS 2017 15.3 and VS Mac 7.1 and with that to Xamarin.Android 7.4. Since then nearly all my EF Core queries are not working anymore and the app crashes with the Exception System.PlatformNotSupportedException.

The message is:

```
Operation is not supported on this platform.
```

This is the stack trace I get when I activate diagnostic logging:

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.IsComObject (System.Object o) [0x00000] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.IsComObject (System.Object obj) [0x00003] in <0c600cab29754882aa1761854aaa8abf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.IsDynamicallyTypedRuntimeProxy (System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject argument, Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo info) [0x00011] in <0c600cab29754882aa1761854aaa8abf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.DeduceArgumentRestriction (System.Int32 parameterIndex, Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.ICSharpInvokeOrInvokeMemberBinder callPayload, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject argument, Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo info) [0x00011] in <0c600cab29754882aa1761854aaa8abf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.Bind (System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder action, Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder binder, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] args, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] arginfos, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject onBindingError) [0x000a3] in <0c600cab29754882aa1761854aaa8abf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpInvokeMemberBinder.FallbackInvokeMember (System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject target, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] args, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion) [0x0000e] in <0c600cab29754882aa1761854aaa8abf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Dynamic.InvokeMemberBinder.FallbackInvokeMember (System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject target, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] args) [0x00000] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject.BindInvokeMember (System.Dynamic.InvokeMemberBinder binder, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] args) [0x0000b] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Dynamic.InvokeMemberBinder.Bind (System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject target, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] args) [0x00016] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind (System.Object[] args, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[T] parameters, System.Linq.Expressions.LabelTarget returnLabel) [0x000c6] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T] (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1[T] site, System.Object[] args) [0x00019] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet] (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) [0x000fc] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalSqlGenerationHelper.GenerateLiteral (System.Object value, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping typeMapping) [0x00086] in <1ce4ae811dd94fe5a5e10e630f2f4c7a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.DefaultQuerySqlGenerator.VisitConstant (System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression expression) [0x0002a] in <1ce4ae811dd94fe5a5e10e630f2f4c7a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression.Accept (System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor visitor) [0x00000] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression node) [0x00005] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ThrowingExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) [0x0003f] in <0a52ab02a5054a9e94c0cd3993f4d33a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.DefaultQuerySqlGenerator.VisitBinary (System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression expression) [0x0012d] in <1ce4ae811dd94fe5a5e10e630f2f4c7a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept (System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor visitor) [0x00000] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression node) [0x00005] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ThrowingExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) [0x0003f] in <0a52ab02a5054a9e94c0cd3993f4d33a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.DefaultQuerySqlGenerator.VisitSelect (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Expressions.SelectExpression selectExpression) [0x0015f] in <1ce4ae811dd94fe5a5e10e630f2f4c7a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Expressions.SelectExpression.Accept (System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor visitor) [0x0001e] in <1ce4ae811dd94fe5a5e10e630f2f4c7a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression node) [0x00005] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ThrowingExpressionVisitor.Visit (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) [0x0002c] in <0a52ab02a5054a9e94c0cd3993f4d33a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.DefaultQuerySqlGenerator.GenerateSql (System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parameterValues) [0x00043] in <1ce4ae811dd94fe5a5e10e630f2f4c7a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.GetRelationalCommand (System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parameters) [0x00025] in <1ce4ae811dd94fe5a5e10e630f2f4c7a>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator+<BufferlessMoveNext>d__9.MoveNext () [0x0041d] in <1ce4ae811dd94fe5a5e10e630f2f4c7a>:0 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator+<MoveNext>d__8.MoveNext () [0x00140] in <1ce4ae811dd94fe5a5e10e630f2f4c7a>:0 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+SelectAsyncEnumerable`2+SelectAsyncEnumerator+<MoveNext>d__4[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x0006e] in <2645c1c7345546f5b968e91de81e2b12>:0 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+SelectAsyncEnumerable`2+SelectAsyncEnumerator+<MoveNext>d__4[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x0006e] in <2645c1c7345546f5b968e91de81e2b12>:0 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor`1+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor+<MoveNext>d__5[T].MoveNext () [0x0016e] in <2645c1c7345546f5b968e91de81e2b12>:0 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions+<ToListAsync>d__129`1[TSource].MoveNext () [0x000b7] in <2645c1c7345546f5b968e91de81e2b12>:0 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at ConnectContacts.Service.DataServices.ContactDataService+<GetContactsExceptMe>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00038] in /Users/npadrutt/Documents/GitHub/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts.Service/DataServices/ContactDataService.cs:110 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at ConnectContacts.Business.ViewModels.ContactListViewModel+<LoadData>d__27.MoveNext () [0x00067] in /Users/npadrutt/Documents/GitHub/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts.Business/ViewModels/ContactListViewModel.cs:134 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at ConnectContacts.Business.ViewModels.ContactListViewModel+<ViewAppeared>d__26.MoveNext () [0x00020] in /Users/npadrutt/Documents/GitHub/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts/ConnectContacts.Business/ViewModels/ContactListViewModel.cs:124 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <183b200ee49746d48fc781625979428e>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <71828dd8fb5f4508815e23d6996c45c2>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <71828dd8fb5f4508815e23d6996c45c2>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <71828dd8fb5f4508815e23d6996c45c2>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:51155536-39dc-466e-a95f-dea6c3e2125b (intptr,intptr)
```

One of the queries who failes is:

```
var list = await contactRepository
                .GetAll()
                .Where(x => x.IsMe)
                .ToListAsync();
```

When I remove the where clause it works.

Another where I could solve was when I changed the following:

```
query.Where(x => x.Infos.Any())
                .Where(x => x.Infos.Any(e => e.InfoType.ToString()
                                .StartsWith("Number", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

to:

```
 query.Where(x => x.Infos.Any(e => e.InfoType.ToString()
                                .StartsWith("Number", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

I use EF Core 1.1.2 and EF Core SQLite 1.1.2.

Since there was a update to EF Core 2.0 I thought maybe this is fixable with an update. But EF core is only supported from Xamarin.Android 7.5 which is right now not available. So an update is not possible..

I talked with other developer who have similar isses. What's wrong here and how can I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure that the EF Core dll referenced in the Android project is the Android specific target dll?

Comment: I have now reason to think otherwise. I removed the nuget packages and readded it again. The error is still the same.

Comment: Check the paths for the dll's it adds to be 100% sure.

Comment: How can I check that when I use a poeject.json file? AFAIK there are no paths in there and neither are in the csproj.

Comment: So you've only installed EFCore into your NET Standard project? What about the Android project?

Comment: no, I removed the packages.config in my android project and replaced it with a project.json.

Comment: But project.json is deprecated

Comment: It wasn't when I did that :) but I will move it back and see if that helps.

Comment: Alright, I moved it to packages.config. But the error persists. Referenced is the .netstandard 1.3 package. That's the correct packages as far as I can see, since there is just this and a .net451 one.

Comment: As work around I decided to use dapper.net ORM to do my lookup queries. Not an elegant solution I know but one that at least does not stall the project until a fix is issued

Comment: probably related to this issue: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101265/vs-15-3-dynamic-keyword-throws-platformnotsupportedexception-workaround

Comment: Having the same issue with dynamic objects since the update for VS2017 on Mac - worked absolutely fine before, now I am getting a similar error.  Super annoying

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57919
There is a patch in this thread that might help your issue, about to check it now and see if it fixes the dynamic object problem

Comment: As far as I could see the patch was just for ios, right? My main issue is on android right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in VS 15.3.2

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57919
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58846

https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-15-3-2/